# Unit testing a ThreeJS application with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, three.js, jestjs

I am having difficulties testing a JavaScript file with Jest which encapsulate a lot of interactions with ThreeJS. I first tried not to mock ThreeJS, which did not work :

```
  ● TestSuite › Should instantiate a renderer attached to a specific element of the DOM

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getExtension' of null

      36 |      */
      37 |     constructor(containerId: string) {
    > 38 |         this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
      39 |         this.attachRenderer(containerId);
      40 |         this.createCamera();
      41 |         this.createScene();
```

That's normal, because we are [testing in a browser-like environment which has no webgl context](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3905) . So what I did to solve this problem was mocking three.js.

I then mocked my external module with `jest.mock("three");`

```
  ● TestSuite › Should instantiate a renderer attached to a specific element of the DOM

    TypeError: this.renderer.setSize is not a function

      64 |             throw new Error("Cannot find DOM element object matching the specified ID: " + containerId);
      65 |         }
    > 66 |         this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      67 |         element.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
      68 |     }
      69 |
```

And that's expected behavior, since every mock from jest returns `undefined`, `new WebGLRenderer();` returns `undefined` and I cannot do anything with it.

My current work-around is to define everything I uses in ThreeJS in my test file :

```
jest.mock("three", () => ({
    Scene: class Scene {
        public add(): void {
            return;
        }
    },
    WebGLRenderer: class WebGlRenderer {
        public render(): void {
            return;
        }
        public setSize(): void {
            return;
        }
    }
    // And a lot more...
}));
```

But I am well aware that this is not the optimal solution. Before that I was doing the same thing, but in a file in mocks/three.js ( https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks ), which was also working fine but that does not satisfy my need.

Is there a way to test this file properly, without having to write tons of manual mocks of threejs ?

Comment: check out https://github.com/dbkaplun/three-snapshot-serializer/blob/master/test/createSerializer.test.js

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on webgl this and solved this in following way.
https://github.com/AmitTeli/webgl-three-test

The summary of the approach is

1. Move all the **global variables** like **scene**, **renderer** and **camera** to *index.html*
2. Initialize them on loading of the page. e.g. in this reactjs example, they are initialized in *componentDidMount()* of the root component. Other functions can use this context. (You can check this by running **`yarn start`**)
3. While doing the unit testing, initialize them in *setupTest.js*. We will need additional dev dependencies of headless webgl - **gl** and **canvas**
4. With this setup now we can run the test in say *App.test.js* (You can check this by running **`yarn test`**)