# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getShaderPrecisionFormat' of undefined when using Threejs and jest

Tags: three.js, jestjs, webgl

I'm pretty knew to all the technologies in this q, so please bear with me

Following on from this question:  [Unit testing a ThreeJS application with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330753/unit-testing-a-threejs-application-with-jest)

I have implemented the solution in the answer and so have created this function to mock the viewport:

```
export function createViewPort () {
  const canvasGL = new Canvas.Canvas(1000, 1000)

  canvasGL.addEventListener = function (event, func, bind_) {
    // mock function to avoid errors inside THREE.WebGlRenderer()
  }
  const glContext = gl(1, 1)
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ context: glContext, antialias: true, canvas: canvasGL })
  var mvp = new BaseViewPort()
  mvp.initialise(1000, 1000, renderer)
  return mvp
}
```

BaseViewPort is my class which creates a camera and a scene.

I then use this in my jest tests and all runs fine on my local machine (windows pc).  When I push this up to the git repository and the build then runs on the server which run in linux, I get the error below:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getShaderPrecisionFormat' of undefined`

I don't have a clue where to start with looking what might cuase this. Obviously there is some difference between the two environments.  Any ideas where I might start looking?  Should I be using jest.mock to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the virtual machine that is set up to run the tests was not configured to have a graphics cards and the webgl renderer needs one to work.  Also what I was trying to do was more of an integration test than a unit test so change my code structure a bit so that I did not need to load threejs at all and could mock the viewport more cleanly.